# Call Fortran subroutine from Python on Windows compiled using gfortran using f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

For the Fortran subroutine

```
subroutine sum_absolute(n, x, sum_abs_x)
! return the sum of the absolute values of x
implicit none
integer         , intent(in)  :: n
double precision, intent(in)  :: x(n)
double precision, intent(out) :: sum_abs_x
sum_abs_x = sum(abs(x))
end subroutine sum_absolute
```

and Python script

```
import numpy as np
import fortran_subroutines

# call the sum_absolute subroutine
n = 5
x = np.array([-1, 2, -3, 4, -5], dtype=np.float64)
print("x =", x)
sum_abs_x = fortran_subroutines.sum_absolute(n, x)
print(sum_abs_x) # should print 15.0
```

I compile and run on Windows with GNU Fortran (GCC) 13.0.0 20221218 and Python 3.11.1 installed:

```
f2py -c -m fortran_subroutines sum_abs.f90 --compiler=mingw32
python xfortran_sub.py
```

but get an error

```
x = [-1.  2. -3.  4. -5.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\...\xfortran_sub.py", line 8, in <module>
    sum_abs_x = fortran_subroutines.sum_absolute(n, x)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
fortran_subroutines.error: (shape(x, 0) == n) failed for 1st keyword n: sum_absolute:n=-1
```

How do I fix this? A file `fortran_subroutines.cp311-win_amd64.pyd` has been created.

Edit:

Adding f2py directives to the Fortran code to give

```
subroutine sum_absolute(n, x, sum_abs_x)
! return the sum of the absolute values of x
implicit none
integer         , intent(in)  :: n
double precision, intent(in)  :: x(n)
double precision, intent(inout) :: sum_abs_x
!f2py intent(in) n
!f2py intent(in) x(n)
!f2py intent(in,out) sum_abs_x
sum_abs_x = sum(abs(x))
end subroutine sum_absolute
```

the program runs but gives wrong output of

```
x = [-1.  2. -3.  4. -5.]
5.0
```

Edit: when I modify the order of arguments in the Python call to `sum_absolute()` to

```
sum_abs_x = sum_absolute(x, n)
```

the result is correct. A related question is [f2py - order of function arguments messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528927/f2py-order-of-function-arguments-messed-up).

Comment: With your "Edit:"s you seem to have solved all your problems. Can you clarify what remains in your question?